# Google App Engine run command after deploy

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, app.yaml

Is there a way to run a list of linux commands on the docker after deployement finish automatically, like lifecycle (valable for Kubernetes ) on the yaml file?

I do not want to have to ssh to the instance and run my command.
I need to install `ssh-client` and some time `vim` and other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are looking for a solution to this problem.
App Engine with **runtime: python** or other default source in the app.yaml, there won't be too much customization.
To be able to create your own build you have to use **runtime: custom** and add **Dockerfile** file in same directory (root).
This is what it looks like:

**app.yaml**:
Only the first line change.

```
    runtime: custom

    # the PROJECT-DIRECTORY is the one with settings.py and wsgi.py
    entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT mysite.wsgi # specific to a GUnicorn HTTP server deployment
    env: flex # for Google Cloud Flexible App Engine

    # any environment variables you want to pass to your application.
    # accessible through os.environ['VARIABLE_NAME']
    env_variables:
    # the secret key used for the Django app (from PROJECT-DIRECTORY/settings.py)
      SECRET_KEY: 'lkfjop8Z8rXWbrtdVCwZ2fMWTDTCuETbvhaw3lhwqiepwsfghfhlrgldf'
      DEBUG: 'False' # always False for deployment
      DB_HOST: '/cloudsql/app-example:us-central1:example-postgres'
      DB_PORT: '5432' # PostgreSQL port
      DB_NAME: 'example-db'
      DB_USER: 'mysusername'   # either 'postgres' (default) or one you created on the PostgreSQL instance page
      DB_PASSWORD: 'sgvdsgbgjhrhytriuuyokkuuywrtwerwednHUQ'

      STATIC_URL: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/example/static/' # this is the url that you sync static files to
      
    automatic_scaling:
        min_num_instances: 1
        max_num_instances: 2

    handlers:
    - url: /static
      static_dir: static

    beta_settings:
      cloud_sql_instances: app-example:us-central1:example-postgres

    runtime_config:
      python_version: 3 # enter your Python version BASE ONLY here. Enter 2 for 2.7.9 or 3 for 3.6.4
```

**Dockerfile**:

```
    FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/python


    # Create a virtualenv for dependencies. This isolates these packages from
    # system-level packages.
    # Use -p python3 or -p python3.7 to select python version. Default is version 2.
    RUN virtualenv /env -p python3


    # Setting these environment variables are the same as running
    # source /env/bin/activate.
    ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
    ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH


    # Install custom linux packages (python-qt4 for open-cv)
    RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install vim python-qt4 ssh-client git -y


    # Add the application source code and install all dependencies into the virtualenv
    ADD . /app
    RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

    # add my ssh key for github
    RUN mv /app/.ssh / && \
        chmod 600 /.ssh/*



    # Run a WSGI server to serve the application.
    EXPOSE 8080

    # gunicorn must be declared as a dependency in requirements.txt.
    WORKDIR /app
    CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 Blacks.wsgi:application --timeout 0 --preload && \
        python3 manage.py makemigrations && \
        python3 manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

App Engine is Serverless solution. In product [description](https://cloud.google.com/appengine#all-features) you may find:

> **Fully managed**
>
> A fully managed environment lets you focus on code while
> App Engine manages infrastructure concerns.

This means that, if you choose App Engine you don't have to care about server. So as design, it's for those who do not want to have any access to server, but focus on code leaving all server maintenance to GCP. I think the main feature is automatic scaling of the app.

We do not know what do you intend to do, you can review the [app.yaml reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref) to find all features available. The configuration is different depending of the language environment you want to use.

If you want to have access to environment you should use Kubernetes solutions or even Compute engine.

I hope it will help somehow!

Answer (score 0):

Another simple workaround would be to create a separate URL handler that will run your shell script. For example `/migrate`. And after deployment, you may use curl to trigger that URL.

Please note that in such case anybody, who would try to find some secret URLs of your backend may find it and trigger it as many times, as they want. So if you need to ensure only trusted people can trigger it - you should either:

- come up with more secret URL than just `/migrate`
- check permissions inside this view (but in such case it will be more difficult to call it via curl, cause you'll also need to pass some auth data)

Example basic view (using python + django rest framework):

```py
from io import StringIO

from django.core.management import call_command
from rest_framework.renderers import StaticHTMLRenderer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView


class MigrateView(APIView):
    permission_classes = ()
    renderer_classes = [StaticHTMLRenderer]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        out = StringIO()
        # --no-color because ANSI symbols (used for colors)
        # render incorrectly in browser/curl
        call_command('migrate', '--no-color', stdout=out)
        return Response(out.getvalue())
```